# How to replace specific value in Json based on condition in Mule(3) Dataweave 1.0

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mule4

I have a Json Input like below, where if  `doa` is null or "" it needs to replace with the value `test`  if it contains Value then no change required. I have achieved in dwl 2  version using `update`. Using  mabObject in dataweave 1.0 version, but it is not working out. Looking for your expertise. Thanks

Input:

```
 {
    "sets": {
        "exd": {
            "cse": {
                "doa": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Achieved in dwl 2 :

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
import * from dw::util::Values
---
 if 
 (!isEmpty (payload.sets.exd.cse.doa )) payload
 else
 payload  update
  {
    case .sets.exd.cse.doa! -> "test"
}
```

Response

```
     {
     "sets": {
        "exd": {
            "cse": {
                "doa": "test"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looking for Mule 3 dataweave 1.0 version of it??

Answer (score 1):

This is a lesser backport of the update operator in DataWeave 2.0 to DataWeave 1.0 as a function. The keys parameter is the sequence of keys as an array as strings. I added a check for key null or empty as it can be done in DataWeave 1.0.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%function updateKey(o,keys,value)
    o match {
        :object -> o mapObject ($$): 
                    updateKey($, keys[1 to -1], value )
                        when ($$ ~= keys[0] and ((sizeOf keys) >1))
                        otherwise ($ 
                            when ((sizeOf keys) >1) otherwise value
                        ),
                                        
        default -> $ 
    }
---
updateKey(payload, ["sets", "exd", "cse", "doa"], "test") when (payload.sets.exd.cse.doa is :null or payload.sets.exd.cse.doa == "") otherwise payload
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but unfortunately it has a side effect of updating EVERY value in the base object if you have more than one key. E.g.:
{
    "sets": {
        "exd": {
            "cse": {
                "doa": null,
                "some other key": "some other value"
            }
        }
    }
}
Output:
{
    "sets": {
        "exd": {
            "cse": {
                "doa": "test",
                "some other key": "test"
            }
        }
    }
}
I haven't figured out how to limit the update to just the targeted key.

Answer (score 0):

If / else statements work considerably differently in dataweave 1.0, `update` doesn't exist, and I don't know if `isEmpty` exists as part of core - don't think so. If you know ahead of time the structure of the object, you can simply build a new object like this:

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json
---
payload when (payload.sets.exd.cse.doa != '' and payload.sets.exd.cse.doa != null) 
otherwise {
  sets: {
    exd: {
      cse: {
        data: "test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment to @aled's solution, here is an update that will limit the change to the specific key even if there are multiple key-value pairs at the target level:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

%function updateKey(o,keys,value)
    o match {
        :object -> o mapObject ($$): 
                    updateKey($, keys[1 to -1], value )
                        when ($$ ~= keys[0] and ((sizeOf keys) >1))
                        otherwise ($ when (((sizeOf keys) >1) or '$$' != keys[0]) 
                            otherwise value
                        ),                                        
        default -> $ 
    }
---
updateKey(payload, ["sets", "exd", "cse", "doa"], "test") when (payload.sets.exd.cse.doa is :null or payload.sets.exd.cse.doa == "") otherwise payload
```